# Return value in a callback function in Python

Tags: python

I have the following codes:

```
from time import sleep
from pybit import spot
ws_spot = spot.WebSocket(
    test=True,
    ping_interval=30,  # the default is 30
    ping_timeout=10,  # the default is 10
    domain="bybit"  # the default is "bybit"
)
def handle_message(msg):
    print(msg)

ws_spot.depth_v2_stream(
    handle_message, "ETHUSDT"
)
while True:
    sleep(1)
```

I want to modify the function "handle_message" so that it may return value. I tried

```
from time import sleep
from pybit import spot
ws_spot = spot.WebSocket(
    test=True,
    ping_interval=30,  # the default is 30
    ping_timeout=10,  # the default is 10
    domain="bybit"  # the default is "bybit"
)

def handle_message(msg):
    return msg

x = handle_message(msg)

ws_spot.depth_v2_stream(
    handle_message, "ETHUSDT"
)
while True:
    print(x)
```

However, it doesn't work as the "msg" is not defined.
May I know how can I return value in this case? Thank you.

Comment: You can't do it that way.  YOU aren't calling that function, `depth_v2_stream` is calling it.  If you want to retain some information, you will have to use a `global` or make it a class.

Comment: What are you expecting `x = handle_message(msg)` to do? No message has been received, what should it return?

Comment: May I know how can I make it a class? Since the "msg" is called. I do not know how I can "return msg" but calling a function with argument "msg". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what your code is trying, but this is the KIND of thing you need:

```
from time import sleep
from pybit import spot
ws_spot = spot.WebSocket(
    test=True,
    ping_interval=30,  # the default is 30
    ping_timeout=10,  # the default is 10
    domain="bybit"  # the default is "bybit"
)

savedmsg = None
def handle_message(msg):
    global savedmsg
    savedmsg = msg
    print(msg)

ws_spot.depth_v2_stream(
    handle_message, "ETHUSDT"
)

while not savedmsg:
    sleep(1)

print(savedmsg)
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. Yes, using global variable will work. I want to use a return value method to get the value. Is there any way I can do this by using a return value method? Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, because YOU aren't calling the function.  It's called by `depth_v2_stream`, so if you return something, it is returned to `depth_v2_stream`, which will throw it away.  You have to use out-of-band communication.